# Aren't questions asking for clarification on a homework question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I saw [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28648150/java-homework-help-o) on stackoverflow yesterday while browsing through the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag.

The instant I saw the title and the content, I thought that it was yet another one of those questions in which the OP just dump his homework and expect us to do it.

But on looking at it more carefully, I saw that the OP wanted to clarify a doubt on his/her homework. The OP did not seem to understand the homework question. But unfortunately, the OP was at once greeted with harsh downvotes, negative comments and close-votes as if the OP's question was the type of "Gimme teh codez" question.

So my question is, **Aren't questions which ask for clarification of a homework question on-topic for StackOverflow?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take a look at [what questions can be asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

I wouldn't classify this under any of the bullets above: there's no code, there's nothing programming-specific, it's obviously not a software tool and the're nothing software-specific about this algorithm.

So by the letter of the law, I would already deny it.

What's more though is that we are not in the business of explaining homework assignments. People get paid to do that and are just an email or a raised hand away: they're called teachers/TA's.

This question won't provide any future value either, he hasn't indicated what the specific part is that he doesn't understand nor that he made a meaningful attempt at understanding (by for example drawing the situation).

All together that's too many red strikes and I hereby banish it.

Comment: And you didn't even have to get out all the "don't ask" page.